# Distinct values with pluck

Tags: php, laravel, distinct, laravelcollective, pluck

I'm trying to retrieve data from database and bind them to a html select tag, and to bind them I need to use pluck so I get the field I want to show in a array(key => value), because of FORM::select. The normal pluck gets all the results, while I want to use distinct. My model is Room and it looks like:

```
class Room extends Eloquent
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $casts = [
        'price' => 'float',
        'floor' => 'int',
        'size' => 'float'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'capacity',
        'description',
        'price',
        'floor',
        'size',
        'type',
        'photo_name'
    ];
}
```

While my function I'm using in the controller look like:

```
public function getRooms()
{
    $roomType = Room::pluck('type','type');
    $roomFloor = Room::pluck('floor','floor');

    return view('roomgrid')->with('type',$roomType)->with('floor',$roomFloor);
}
```

And my view contains this piece of code to get floors:

```
{{FORM::select('floor', $floor, null,['class'=>'basic'])}}
```

Like this I get duplicated floors, that I don't want. Is there any way so I can get distinct floors and pluck them?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Why not use `groupBy()`?

```
$roomType = Room::groupBy('type')->pluck('type','type');
```

Comment: I was using this backwards and it wasn't working xd. It worked, thanks for the fast answer.

Comment: Yeah backwards it will not work because pluck get's array not Collection object. If you had ->get() instead of pluck() it will get Collection object but groupBy will create nested array. So you only need to use eloquent to simply call MYSQL GROUP BY query and that's it.

Comment: I am just curious, why you have given two parameters to pluck ? Cant it be: `Room::groupBy('type')->pluck('type');` ?

Comment: @Learner He needed key and value to be the same as I understood from his examples.

Comment: in terms of performance - this is the best eloquent solution?

Answer (score 20):

```
Room::unique('floor')->pluck('floor', 'floor');
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-unique

Comment: Works on collection not on query builder

Answer (score 12):

[distinct](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#selects) can do the trick:

```
Room::query()->distinct()->pluck('type');
```

Which will be translated into the following SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT type FROM rooms
```

Answer (score 6):

you can do this

```
    $roomType = Room::pluck('type')->unique();
    $roomFloor = Room::pluck('floor')->unique();
```

Answer (score 4):

#### 2019 Update

You don't need to use 2 arguments with `pluck()`

simply do:

```
$roomType = Room::groupBy('type')->pluck('type');
```

of course for getting it into array:

```
$roomType = Room::groupBy('type')->pluck('type')->toArray();
```

Sometimes I use the result for `whereIn` clause, its useful for that.

Comment: toArray doesn't work in laravel 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [KeyBy](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-keyby) or pluck with same key-Value pair to pick Distinct Values.
PHP array can only have unique keys.From this Idea we can get Unique models based on Array key.

```
Room::keyBy('floor')->pluck('floor');
```

or

```
Room::pluck('floor', 'floor');
```