# Using group by and pluck together?

Tags: laravel

I get data from my model, and I then use `groupBy` on the collection, to group all results into their own types.

I then have an array of each `type` with various model collections underneath them.

How can I `pluck` only the `title` and `content` attributes from each model, underneath each group `type`.

Normally I would use `pluck` but it fails to work when using `groupBy`.

Something like: `MyModel::orderByDesc('date')->get()->groupBy('type')`

But only then return particular attributes for each `type`.

Comment: if you use `->get()`, you complete the query and you get a collection object. So you'll likely want to use the SQL `groupBy()` which must be called before `->get()`.

Comment: @Flame nope, that won't return all rows for each grouping, it must be used on the collection, not model.

Comment: Anothe option is to go down the plucking unique/distinct values: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42447682/560287

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use map method:

```
MyModel::orderByDesc('date')
   ->get()
   ->groupBy('type')
   ->map(fn($type) => $type->pluck('title'));
```

Tested on:

```
$a = [['a' => 'type1', 'b' => 'one'], ['a' => 'type2', 'b' => 'two'], ['a' => 'type2', 'b' => 'three']];

collect($a)->groupBy('a')->map(fn($type) => $type->pluck('b'));

Illuminate\Support\Collection {#4527
     all: [
       "type1" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#4521
         all: [
           "one",
         ],
       },
       "type2" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#4529
         all: [
           "two",
           "three",
         ],
       },
     ],
   }
```

Comment: @panthro you deleted comment :) I added testing suite